# De onde vem a expressão "pisar na jaca"?

Tags: origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas, girias

Conheci em criança a expressão "pisar no jacá". Usava-se para pessoas que transportavam alimentos em jacás, espécie de cestas que se apoiavam na cabeceira da sela dos animais de montaria. Eram duas cestas, uma de cada lado, embaixo delas ficava o estribo, onde o cavaleiro tinha de pisar para subir à sela. Mas, quando esses transportadores rústicos bebiam muito, dizia-se que "pisavam no jacá" em vez de pisar no estribo. Para minha surpresa, vi mais de 40 anos depois o que suspeito seja a mesma expressão modificada para "pisar na jaca", que me parece absolutamente sem sentido. Creio que pode ter surgido com o introdução do telex nos anos 70. O aparelho não tinha acentuação. Em caso de acento agudo na última sílaba, era necessário adicionar-se a letra "h" no final da palavra. Quem sabe deixou-se de empregar a letra mágica em algum momento da comunicação e a expressão se transformou dessa forma?

Comment: Não sei dizer se esta é a real origem do termo "pisar na jaca", mas de qualquer jeito é bastante interessante!

Comment: Encontrei nalguns sites, como o [Brasil Escola](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/curiosidades/enfiar-pe-na-jaca.htm), que diz precisamente que a expressão original é "enfiar o pé no jacá", porque os tropeiros bêbados faziam isso mesmo ao montar a cavalgadura. Mas ninguém explica como é que sabe isso! Nomeadamente, ninguém apresenta um exemplo documentado antigo do uso da expressão. A ideia do telex, não sei não: "enfiar o pé no jacá" ou "na jaca" seria algo que as pessoas enviavam frequentemente por telex?

Answer (score 3):

Em pt-BR, **"Meter o pé na jaca" ou "enfiar o pé na jaca" refere-se a cometer excessos, principalmente etílicos e/ou gastronômicos.**

Ao contrário do que é dito na pergunta, "pisar na jaca" me parece uma metáfora bem mais ilustrativa do que "pisar no jacá". A jaca é uma fruta grande, de casca grossa e áspera porém friável, e relativamente mole e grudenta por dentro.  Ao contrário de outras frutas como a maçã ou o côco, se tu meteres o pé em uma jaca madura, teu pé e tornozelo vão ficar, no mínimo, todos lambuzados.

A expressão em pt-BR é "meter o pé na jaca" e, ao que me consta, tornou-se conhecida em todo o Brasil por ocasião da exibição de "Pé na Jaca", *telenovela brasileira produzida e exibida no horário das 19 horas, pela Rede Globo, de 20 de novembro de 2006 a 15 de junho de 2007.*

Quanto à origem, **"meter o pé no jacá"** é a expressão mais antiga, o que não significa que "meter o pé na jaca" tenha tido aí a sua origem. Mesmo porque, pouca gente sabe o que é "jacá". Já a nossa jaca é uma fruta comum em todo o território brasileiro. Meter o pé na jaca, no meu entender, presta-se bem mais ao que veio a significar, do que "meter o pé no jacá". Veja o que diz o professor **[Sérgio Rodrigues](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/pe-na-jaca-ou-pe-no-jaca/)**:

> As duas formas são usadas. Como o uso, no caso de expressões idiomáticas, tem indiscutível soberania, não se pode dizer que exista uma certa e uma errada. Parece provável que “meter o pé no jacá” ou “estar com o pé no jacá” seja anterior, a origem de tudo, e a jaca, fruto da jaqueira, tenha entrado nessa história mais tarde por semelhança sonora. O fato é que entrou e vai ser difícil tirá-la de lá, mesmo porque o “pé na jaca” é hoje dominante – e pouca gente sabe o que é jacá.  A relativa obscuridade da palavra jacá bastaria para explicar a metamorfose ocorrida desde então, mas **é preciso registrar que, além disso, a imagem de um pé enfiado numa jaca gorda e visguenta, com seu cheiro estonteante, tem uma expressividade que nos ajuda a compreender o fato de a expressão ter caído no gosto dos falantes.**   “Cair no gosto”, a propósito, é uma expressão idiomática que passou por processo semelhante, tendo surgido como variação da antiga “cair no goto” (ou seja, na glote), que hoje – felizmente, eu diria – quase ninguém usa.

Comment: Pois é, eu ja tinha dado um texto desse mesmo professor. É uma pena não verificar o que colocam os outros.

Comment: @Lambie,  Quando comecei a escrever, não havia ainda nenhuma resposta.  Nós dois escrevemos nossas respostas ao mesmo tempo.  A diferença de 11 minutos a seu favor deveu-se ao fato de que minha resposta foi mais extensa, metade dela foi redigida por mim, e eu sou um "slow typist".   Não creio que isso seja motivo para animosidades.

Comment: Tudo bem. Entendo.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é isso:

http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/pe-na-jaca-ou-pe-no-jaca/

> As duas formas são usadas. Como o uso, no caso de expressões
>   idiomáticas, tem indiscutível soberania, não se pode dizer que exista
>   uma certa e uma errada. Parece provável que “meter o pé no jacá” ou
>   “estar com o pé no jacá” seja anterior, a origem de tudo, e a jaca,
>   fruto da jaqueira, tenha entrado nessa história mais tarde por
>   semelhança sonora. O fato é que entrou e vai ser difícil tirá-la de
>   lá, mesmo porque o “pé na jaca” é hoje dominante – e pouca gente sabe
>   o que é jacá. [...]
>
> A origem dessa denominação do pileque remonta aos tempos em que os
>   bares tinham, na parte da frente, cestos com frutas e legumes. Era o
>   modelo botequim-quitanda. E era nos cestos de palha, chamados jacás,
>   que ficavam os artigos à venda. Quando alguém bebia demais, ao sair,
>   enfiava o pé no jacá.

- Atualizado em 18 fev 2017.